# Get Prefab Script from PlayerController ( Unity )

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi guys so I am currently developing a simple game and I have a script called

PlayerController.cs , GameManager.cs and PowerUps.cs

On my GameManager.cs

I spawn my powerup like this

```
//Add GameObject for Powerup
public GameObject PowerUp;

    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnPowerUps());
    }

//Spawn Powerups
    IEnumerator SpawnPowerUps()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //pop ups the powerup every 20s
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
            if (player.clicked)
            {
                Instantiate(PowerUp, new Vector3(Random.Range(0, (float)0.9), 0, Random.Range(player.transform.position.z + 40, player.transform.position.z + 80)), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now my PowerUp.cs is attached to the prefab and every time the player hit the powerups it will destroy and add a speed to the PlayerController.cs

```
PlayerController player;
    public int powerUps = 0;


    void Start()
    {
        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(powerUps >= 1)
        {
            //change the speed of the player
            player.Speed = 5f;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Power Up has been picked up. Destroying power up!");
            powerUps += 1;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

now my script for my PlayerController.cs

```
void Update(){
   if ((Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))
   {
      Speed = 3.0f;
   }
}
```

but the problem is that the speed is not changing to `5.0f` it still remains as `3.0f`

#EDIT
i've checked the if the powerup can get the playercontroller and it is not null so basically it can get the playercontroller script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the powerups and then destroy it. What you need to do is set the player.Speed in the collision.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Power Up has been picked up. Destroying power up!");
        
         PlayerController player = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
         if(player != null){
                 player.Speed =5;
                 Destroy(gameObject);
         }
    }
}
```

And the start and update are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Debug.Log in OnCollisionEnter printing out? If it IS printing but Speed still seems to equal 3.0, then it's possible that the speed is getting reset by that code in your PlayerController's Update(). I would put a log in that if-statement in PlayerController.cs to make sure the Speed isn't getting set back to 3.0 after it was set to 5.0.